# set value to $_REQUEST variable in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to assign a value to $_REQUEST variable in PHP? For example:

```
if ($_REQUEST['name'] == "") {
  $_REQUEST['name'] = "John";
}
```

Comment: you tested this? what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `$_REQUEST` is a variable like any other, but can be pre-populated and is superglobal.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that that variable is read only, if you want to save global variable you can try to make a new variable in the global scope, like this :

```
$GLOBALS['some_var'] = 'new var';
```

then you can get the value everywhere in your code, like this :

```
$your_var = $GLOBAS['some_var'];
```